# How to change a Domain Class model object from one derived class to another in Grails/GORM

Tags: inheritance, grails, grails-orm, table-per-hierarchy

Given the following Grails GORM Domain Classes and using table-per-hierarchy inheritance:

```
class Book {
  static belongsTo = [ parent: Parent ]
  String title
}

abstract class Parent {
  static hasMany = [ books: Book ]
}

class A extends Parent {
  String asset
}

class B extends Parent {
  String asset
}
```

Say I have retrieved an instance of class A from the database. I want to convert it to an instance of class B.  What is the grails idiomatic way to do this?

Without the hasMany relation, I would just delete A and create a new B.  But I don't want the overhead of going through a large number of Books and updating their parent_id fields to point to the new B.

Under the hood, I essentially just want to perform an SQL UPDATE to change the database field parent.class from A to B.  So what's the recommended way to do this in GORM/Grails?

Answer (score 1):

There's no support for this in Grails or Hibernate, since it's the analogue of changing an instance of A to a B in-memory, but an object has a fixed type and cannot change. There's no direct access to the discriminator column that you need to change the value of.

So the way to do this is via a SQL update as you say. There are a few options but the best is probably `groovy.sql.Sql`, e.g.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class FooService {
   def dataSource

   void convertToB(A a) {
      def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
      sql.executeUpdate('update parent set class=? where id=?', [B.name, a.id])
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried the native SQL and it actually didn't work in my integration test.  After running the native SQL query, I was still retrieving the old version.  I suspect Hibernate's caching has something to do with it.  But I've gone to using a workaround instead of replacing A with B in the database.  Like you say, this is really going against the grain of GORM and is taking too long as a result.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a sign of design flaw.

You could try to replace inheritance with aggregation - ["Favor object composition over class inheritance." (Gang of Four 1995:20)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Introduction.2C_Chapter_1) - extract a, say, `HasAsset` interface from `Parent` and add a reference to `HasAsset`.

[Groovy delegation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Delegation+Pattern) could help.

Comment: Of course the example above is greatly simplified for posting here, so some meaning has been lost.  What this question is really about is replacing an entry with a specific ID with one of a different type.  That is, ID #5 is no longer an A.  Now it's a B.  You can change everything else about A, why not the type?  But you make a very good point about the Groovy Delegation, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see you point, do you see mine? If you wish to change everything, why using a language element (class inheritance) that can't be changed? The answer you need is not necessary the one to question you asked. I don't mean you're doing everything wrong, just noted that this *might be a sign* of bad decision.