# In Grails, is it possible to change the subtype of a persistent entity?

Tags: grails, discriminator, grails-2.0.4

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Fruit { ... }
class Apple extends Fruit { ... }
class Orange extends Fruit { ... }
```

Let's say a user wants to create a new `Apple`. They pick a type from a dropdown, and I use a service to translate the type string into a concrete type:

```
def fruit = FruitService.createFruit(params.type)
fruit.properties = params
fruit.save()
```

This will successfully save a new `Apple` instance.

Now let's say the user realized that they made a mistake and that they wanted to create an `Orange` instead. In the edit view, I provide the ability for the user to change the type to an `Orange`, but how do I **update** the existing `Apple` instance so that it's now an `Orange`? I cannot simply delete the `Orange` and create a new `Apple` instance because of other relationships. Is this even possible?

Comment: can you elaborate more on the "other relationships" part? If you update apple to become an orange, won't you want to change the relationships associated with the original apple object too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725362/how-to-change-a-domain-class-model-object-from-one-derived-class-to-another-in-g